# Get previous row ID while sorting not on ID

Tags: mysql, sql

How to get the previous & next id from table that has the structure as mentioned below:

```
+----+---------+---------------------+
| id | urgency | timestamp           |
+----+---------+---------------------+
|  1 | 0       | 2013-01-01 00:00:00 |
|  2 | 2       | 2013-01-01 00:00:00 |
|  3 | 1       | 2013-01-05 09:30:00 |
|  4 | 2       | 2013-01-01 00:00:00 |
|  5 | 2       | 2013-01-01 00:00:00 |
|  6 | 1       | 2013-01-06 10:00:00 |
|  7 | 0       | 2013-01-01 00:00:00 |
|  8 | 0       | 2013-01-03 00:00:00 |
|  9 | 1       | 2013-02-01 13:30:00 |
| 10 | 0       | 2013-01-04 00:00:00 |
+----+---------+---------------------+
```

The table is sorted as follows: urgency asc, timestamp asc, id asc

Here is the sorted table:

```
+----+---------+---------------------+
| id | urgency | timestamp           |
+----+---------+---------------------+
|  1 | 0       | 2013-01-01 00:00:00 |
|  7 | 0       | 2013-01-01 00:00:00 |
|  8 | 0       | 2013-01-03 00:00:00 |
| 10 | 0       | 2013-01-04 00:00:00 |
|  3 | 1       | 2013-01-05 09:30:00 |
|  6 | 1       | 2013-01-06 10:00:00 |
|  9 | 1       | 2013-02-01 13:30:00 | <= CURRENT_ID
|  2 | 2       | 2013-01-01 00:00:00 |
|  4 | 2       | 2013-01-01 00:00:00 |
|  5 | 2       | 2013-01-01 00:00:00 |
+----+---------+---------------------+
```

Is there a way to select something from MySQL where the position is CURRENT_ID - 1 or CURRENT_ID + 1?

What I could do is execute a simple query:

```
SELECT
    id
FROM
    MY_TABLE
ORDER BY
    urgency asc,
    timestamp asc,
    id asc
```

Create a loop through result in PHP and finding the right positions, but this is a table that will increase very quick. So it's not an option... Hope there's another solution you can advise

Comment: I doubt it's possible in this manner. You might have more luck just caching the data.

Comment: I don't understand - In your example you would like to find id=6 or 2?

Comment: @Jack, it certainly is possible, see this [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/08ab1/1)

Comment: @PinnyM I meant in a practical manner, but I'll upvote your answer for the effort you've put into it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For previous:

```
SELECT prev.id
FROM my_table current
JOIN my_table prev
  ON (prev.urgency < current.urgency) 
     OR (prev.urgency = current.urgency 
        AND (prev.timestamp < current.timestamp 
            OR (prev.timestamp = current.timestamp AND prev.id < current.id)))
WHERE current.id = @currentId
ORDER BY prev.urgency desc, prev.timestamp desc, prev.id desc
LIMIT 1
```

For next:

```
SELECT next.id
FROM my_table current
JOIN my_table next
  ON (next.urgency > current.urgency) 
     OR (next.urgency = current.urgency 
        AND (next.timestamp > current.timestamp 
            OR (next.timestamp = current.timestamp AND next.id > current.id)))
WHERE current.id = @currentId
ORDER BY next.urgency asc, next.timestamp asc, next.id asc
LIMIT 1
```

[Sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/08ab1/1) here.

Trying to get them both in a single query is more challenging, but can be done with a similar approach using nested groupings in place of a LIMIT.  I doubt you will see much performance benefit in such a complex query and you'll certainly have a harder time maintaining it...